# Sporadic / occasional problems logging into server with Windows AD account (via SSSD)

Tags: sssd

Trying to log into CentOS7 desktop GUI via Windows Remote Desktop Manager with a Windows AD account linked to the server via `SSSD` and seeing...
[image]
Trying to `ssh` in as myuser does not work either, with the terminal telling me...

```bsh
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

What I needed to do to get things working again was to `ssh` in as root, then `cd` to myuser's /home dir. I then see the `sssd` status as...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl ~]# systemctl status sssd
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-22 16:52:28 HST; 9 months 0 days ago
 Main PID: 122026 (sssd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
           ├─122026 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
           ├─122027 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain co.local --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           ├─122028 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
           └─122029 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

Oct 22 18:16:52 airflowetl.co.local [sssd[krb5_child[119918]]][119918]: KDC has no support for encryption type
Oct 22 18:16:52 airflowetl.co.local [sssd[krb5_child[119918]]][119918]: KDC has no support for encryption type
Oct 22 18:17:05 airflowetl.co.local [sssd[krb5_child[120064]]][120064]: KDC has no support for encryption type
Oct 22 18:17:22 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[122027]: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 22 18:17:22 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[122027]: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 22 18:17:22 airflowetl.co.local sssd[be[co.local]][122027]: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provid...ype)
Oct 22 18:17:22 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[122027]: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 22 18:17:22 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[122027]: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 22 18:17:22 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[122027]: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 22 18:17:22 airflowetl.co.local sssd_be[122027]: GSSAPI client step 2
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

My `/etc/sssd.conf` file looks like...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl sssd]# cat sssd.conf

[sssd]
domains = co.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/co.local]
ad_domain = co.local
krb5_realm = CO.LOCAL
auth_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
chpass_provider = ad
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = False
ldap_user_uid_number = uidNumber
ldap_user_gid_number = gidNumber
ldap_group_gid_number = gidNumber
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
default_domain_suffix = co.local
```

Anyone with more experience know what could be going on here? Any debugging advice (has been hard to test since only happens occasionally and have no idea what could relate to it)?